# Elixir and Erlang Records Pattern Matching

Tags: xml, erlang, elixir

How to make this kind of record pattern matching in Elixir?

```
[ #xmlText{value=Rank} ]  = xmerl_xpath:string("//SalesRank/text()", Xml),
```

Bonus: rewrite [this](http://pragdave.me/post/72406303933/a-first-erlang-program) example from Dave Thomas's blog in Elixir.

---

**Update**:

found what was my problem. You have to use

```
defrecord :xmlText, Record.extract(:xmlText, from_lib: 'xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl')
```

to extract the record from XMerL lib into your program as stated [here](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html). Then the `.value` syntax works and the line can be written as follows:

```
rank = Enum.first(xmerl_xpath.string('//SalesRank/text()', xml)).value
```

Comment: Henry, would you please turn that into an answer and mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See question for answer.
(This is at the top of the unanswered list)

Otherwise I found the answer during my investigations in a [blog post](http://elixir-lang.org/blog/2013/12/27/parsing-xml-with-elixir/) on elixir-lang.org

For the most commonly used records:

```
defrecord :xmlElement, Record.extract(:xmlElement, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl")
defrecord :xmlText, Record.extract(:xmlText, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl")
```